# Pandoc: escape HTML option

Tags: pandoc, html-escape-characters

While other markdown implementations have a switch to escape HTML, I couldn't find one for Pandoc.

I want Pandoc to convert `HELLO <blink>WORLD</blink>` to `<p>HELLO &lt;blink>WORLD&lt;/blink></p>`.

Kramdown and Maruku don't seem to support this, how about Pandoc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the extension `raw_html` by using this command to compile:

```
pandoc -f markdown-raw_html -t html
```

Although the output does not exactly matches your expected output because it will also transform `>` to `&gt;`.

Comment: Do you know if it works also for textile input? -f textile-raw_html doesn't seem to work

Comment: Note that this will replace tables that would've been left as `<table></table>` with just `[TABLE]`, losing the information contained in them.