# Pandoc - HTML to Markdown - remove all attributes

Tags: markdown, pandoc

This would seem like a simple thing to do, but I've been unable to find an answer. I'm converting from HTML to Markdown using Pandoc and I would like to strip all attributes from the HTML such as "class" and "id".

Is there an option in Pandoc to do this?

Comment: You can write a Pandoc filter to do that. If you use panflute , within a filter, do something like elem.identifier = '' , elem.classes = [], elem.attributes = {} . Since only a few elements have attributes, you can wrap it in a try clause (or use __slots__ to find out if the elements have attributes).

Comment: You can try disabling extensions `pandoc -t markdown-header_attributes-link_attributes-native_divs-native_spans` and so forth... or yes, write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html)

Answer (score 15):

Consider `input.html`:

```html
<h1 class="test">Hi!</h1>
<p><strong id="another">This is a test.</strong></p>
```

Then, `pandoc input.html -t gfm-raw_html -o output.md`

produces `output.md`:

```
# Hi!

**This is a test.**
```

without the `-t gfm-raw_html`, you would get

```
# Hi! {#hi .test}

**This is a test.**
```

This question is actually similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37168539). I don't think pandoc ever preserves `id` attributes.

Comment: markdown_github-raw_html is deprecated now and can be replaced with gfm

Comment: Gagh! I hope markdown_github-raw_html is not deprecated because it just did the trick for me (pandoc version 2.5), whereas gfm preserved the html tags I was trying to cut out of the conversion.

Comment: Although `markdown_github-raw_html` is deprecated because `markdown_github` is deprecated, you can use `gfm-raw_html` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to remove all attributes and classes. Save the following to a file `remove-attr.lua` and call pandoc with `--lua-filter=remove-attr.lua`.

```lua
function remove_attr (x)
  if x.attr then
    x.attr = pandoc.Attr()
    return x
  end
end

return {{Inline = remove_attr, Block = remove_attr}}
```

Comment: Trying to discard artifacts from HTML that originated from a Microsoft Office product, containing `<span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">value</span>`s around the values of every cell in a table. This worked _as well as_ `-t gfm-raw_html`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am also surprised that this seemingly simple operation didn't yield any result in web search. Ended up writing the following by referring to [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#searching-the-tree) doc and example usages from other SO answers.

The code below also removes the `script` and `style` html tags. On top of that, it will preserve any `src` and `href` attributes. These two should allows for flexibility to fit for your needs (i.e. adapt any needs then use pandoc to convert the returned html to markdown).

```py
# https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#searching-the-tree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

def unstyle_html(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

    # remove all attributes except for `src` and `href`
    for tag in soup.descendants:
        keys = []
        if not isinstance(tag, NavigableString):
            for k in tag.attrs.keys():
                if k not in ["src", "href"]:
                    keys.append(k)
            for k in keys:
                del tag[k]

    # remove all script and style tags
    for tag in soup.find_all(["script", "style"]):
        tag.decompose()

    # return html text
    return soup.prettify()
```